# Server.Transferrequest() and getting the current URL

Tags: asp.net, server.transfer

Say in my 'Page_init()' of "a.aspx" i just have 'server.transferrequest("b.aspx").

This works great, displays the content for "b.aspx" and the browserurl still stays at "a.aspx".

Happy days.

However does anyone know how to see this url from my "b.aspx" (the resulting page)?.

The usual request.rawurl and request.url.absoluteuri both return the current page as "b.aspx".

Comment: Sir, did you solve your task? Because I faced same problem ...

Answer (score 2):

`Server.TransferRequest` performs an asynchronous execution of the specified URL. This means that your client has no clue of was is going on at the server so from your client perspective it's the same page.

If you need to change the actual page (which is the most common) then use `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: I need to keep the original url the same though.

Comment: The only option I see is to save it as a hiddenField. There is no direct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe before you do the transfer you could save the information you need somewhere, then retrieve it when it's needed again.

Comment: storing it in the session. not elegant at all though.

Comment: You could store it in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection. It only retains its items during transfers.

Answer (score 1):

```
NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
headers["RawUrl"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
Server.TransferRequest("b.aspx", true, null, headers);
```

And then use `Headers["RawUrl"]` in `b.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) to get source page that makes server transfer :

```
string previousPagesUrl = PreviousPage.Request.RawUrl;
```

**EDIT :** @maxp, as an answer to your comment, PreviousPage only works for Server.Transfer and cross page postback.

You'll get **null** for **PreviousPage** if  :

- the source page redirects to the destination page.
- a link at source page forwards the page to destination page.

Comment: tricky if the previous page is not one that performed the server.transferrequest, i.e. page c.aspx requests b.aspx

Comment: PreviousPage is set by `Server.Transfer()`, but **NOT** by `Server.TransferRequest()`.   Just verified with tests.  The OP was using `Server.TransferRequest()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this method:

```
public void Transfer(string path, bool preserveForm )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w.aspx

I currently got in the same problem, and I found out that Server object has this parameter on transfer method that gives you the posibility to preserve the original request form or not.